# How to add multiple textview or label on UIImage swift

Tags: swift, uilabel, uitextview

I need a multiple textview on UIImage like this.

I want add multiple view(text+labels) in my imageView.

[image]

Thanks-

Comment: Look my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39745399/3108877

Answer (score 0):

Hope this idea will help you.

- Get X / Y Axis on touch event.
- Pass X / Y axis information to some function which draw dynamic UItextField

  ```
  func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
  {

      if let touch = touches.first {
          let position = touch.location(in: self)
          print(position.x)
          print(position.y)
      }
  }



  func addDynamicTextField(xAxis: CGFloat, yAxis: CGFloat)
  {
      let someFrame = CGRect(x: xAxis, y: yAxis, width: 100.0, height: 30.0)

      let text = UITextField(frame: someFrame)

      imageView.addSubview(text)
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for this good idea But I want resizing, change rotate and change text options by touching.

Comment: Get more on - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717634/swift-how-can-you-rotate-text-for-uibutton-and-uilabel http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/dragging-views-gestures-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial https://github.com/stropdale/Draggable-UIView

Answer (score 0):

Check my detailed example here:

[How to add interactive UILabels on top of a UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39828485/how-to-add-interactive-uilabels-on-top-of-a-uiimageview/40204303#40204303)

The code there add two CALayers that detects taps and changes text. Using the same type of logic, you can add pan/pinch/rotate handlers that will handle move/resize/rotate.

After you wire up the handlers like in that sample, here's the remaining functions:

```
func moveLayer(_ recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let p = recognizer.location(in: self)
    if layer1.editMode {
        layer1.position = p
    }
    if layer2.editMode {
        layer2.position = p
    }
}

func rotateLayer(_ recognizer:UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    let p = recognizer.location(in: self)
    if layer1.editMode {
        layer1.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        layer1.transform = CATransform3DRotate(myRedEye.transform, recognizer.rotation, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);        }
    if layer2.editMode {
        layer2.position = p
    }
}

func resizeLayer(_ recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    _ = recognizer.location(in: self)
    if layer1.editMode {
        layer1.transform = CATransform3DScale(myRedEye.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
        recognizer.scale = 1
    }
    if layer2.editMode {
        layer2.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(myGreenEye.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
    }
}
```

This was code I wrote a year ago and never put in production. If my memory is good, the trickiest part was how iOS differentiates between a pinch and rotate gesture. Since both use two fingers, combining resizing and rotating led to some small unexpected (IMHO) behaviors.